# Difference Between Variable Declared Inside For Loop and Outside Loop

Tags: java, scope

How does the jvm manage the memory for `i` and `j`? What is the difference between `i` and `j` other than their scope?

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i)
}
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
    System.out.println(j)
}
```

Comment: there is no difference apart from Scopes that you know.. All the local variables are managed in the same way by JVM..

Comment: thanks @LuiggiMendoza , I'm unable to find an answer for it, please can you help me by suggesting some article or book with regard to this

Comment: [How Garbage Collection works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html) and [Java's garbage-collected heap](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1996/jw-08-gc.html) will help you to understand.

Comment: May be a sign of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the scope of variables, no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

Its basically the same thing. The only difference is the declaration happens before the loop in the first case and and in the second case it happens before the execution of the loop.

About JVM's memory management, it is basically managed in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent code of this as follows:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     System.out.println(i)
}
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(j)
    }
}
```